# Why would Select By Location appear not to work properly after Multipart to Singlepart?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3, select

I am having issues using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 and the multipart to singlepart feature and then selecting by location.

Basically, I am able to run the multipart to single part feature to split up some of my polygons. I then use Select By Location, setting the parameters to within a polygon in another layer.

The problem being that it does not pick up all the features within that polygon, missing most of the ones that were originally multiparts out.

Has anyone come across anything like this before?

Comment: Are your geometry features in shapefiles or geodatabase formats?

Comment: Sounds unexpected - have you cleared all selections and made sure Select By Location is performing a new selection?

Comment: picture of the offending example would help

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you may not have cleared all selections and made sure Select By Location is performing a New Selection.